# How to check the json encoded id is not null?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I am receiving an json encoded data in my server its in php, and mongo db, i am taking user id its a unique id. when i get the details how can i validate json data, user id not null, now if it empty it will insert in to the db, how can i solve the problem? is there any method to check the user id is not null while json_decode ?

```
{"userid":"","firstName":"John","lastName":"doe"}
```

here user id is null. How can i validate when i receive this id in my server function?

Comment: No, `""` is not `null`. `""` is the empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode the JSON string using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) (with the second parameter set to `TRUE` to get an associative array instead of an object), access the user ID from the array  and use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) to check if it's empty:

```
$str = '{"userid":"","firstName":"John","lastName":"doe"}';
$jsonArr = json_decode($str, TRUE);
$userId = $jsonArr['userid'];

// if user ID value not empty
if (!empty($userId)) {
    // code
}
```

You could also use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/is_null) instead, but it will not return `TRUE` for an empty string (`""`), which you seem to want to discard. `empty()` will catch both `NULL` and an empty string, so it's better suited for this.

Answer (score 0):

By decoding and checking the strlen?

```
$data = json_decode($string);
$idNotNull = strlen($data->userid) !== 0;
```

without decoding, you could use REGEX

`$idNotNull = preg_match('/^\{.*"userid":"(.+)".*\}$/U',$string);`

Comment: Why would you want to use a regex (which is *not* guaranteed to cover all possible situations, with nesting etc.) when there's a perfectly good function for this purpose?

Comment: i agree.. but he said while json_decoded in the question... this is the only way to do it while decoded.

Comment: $request = Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();                  $category = json_decode($request->getBody(), true); i am using these codes for getting the json request, then how can i check condition ?

Comment: @Naveen to be honest, i agree with everyone else, the only real way to do it would be to decode it using json_decode.. if your decoding it then $idNotNull = strlen($category->userid) !== 0; will provide a true / false determining whether the id is empty or not..

Answer (score 0):

How about decoding the array into a PHP array and checking if the `userid` key is set?

```
$decoded_array = json_decode($json_text);
if (array_key_exists("userid", $decoded_array) {
  // exists
} else{
  // doesn't
}
```